# I get a System.InvalidOperationException error when trying to run a test

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

While trying to run a test via Test Explorer in Visual Studio, I keep getting an error on the line of code below.

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains more than one matching element'"

Tried to comment it out, but then the project won't build. The developer who wrote this has now left.

```
private static string ParseSetting(List<XElement> settings, string settingName)
{
    return settings
            .SingleOrDefault(s => s.Attribute("name")
                                    ?.Value.ToLower() == settingName.ToLower())
            ?.Attribute("value")
            ?.Value;
}
```

It should continue to running the test.

Comment: But the exception message is pretty clear: your `settings` contains _more than one_ `XElement` that have an attribute "name" with a value (case-insensitive) equal to `settingsName`. We can't tell you why, because we don't see the content. And we don't know how to fix this, because we don't know what you're about to test and how a successful and useful test should look like.

Comment: Thanks, that helped actually as it made me realise I have two of the same parameters in my settings file, which I didn't know about. Thank you. How do I mark your comment as the answer?